# How to mount CIFS shares in Linux without password, using domain credentials?

Tags: samba, cifs

I have Ubuntu 18.04  boxes, they are members of Windows domain (using sssd). Linux users need to mount CIFS shares from domains fileservers. What should be done in order to implement passwordless mount, using Kerberos SSO?

Answer (score 0):

Done, using pam_mount (Ubuntu18.04, part of MS Windows domain based on sssd):

- apt install keyutils libpam-mount
- Added to /etc/security/pam_mount.conf.xml